# CLion in docker container not finding clang after install

Tags: ubuntu, docker, clang, clion

I have created the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install \
    clang-3.5 \
    wget \
    libxi6 \
    libxrender1 \
    libxtst6 -y && \
  mkdir ~/clion && \
  cd ~/clion && \
  wget \
    -P ~/clion \
    https://download.jetbrains.com/cpp/clion-1.2.4.tar.gz && \
  tar xfz clion-*.tar.gz

CMD /root/clion/clion-1.2.4/bin/clion.sh
```

I build the image with

```
docker build -t clion .
```

and create/run the container using

```
docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY --device /dev/snd --name clion clion
```

CLion opens fine, but it always tells me that it can't find a C/C++ compiler, even though I install clang. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing `clang-3.5` does not link `clang` to `clang-3.5`.

Add these to the Dockerfile:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/clang-3.5 100
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/clang-3.5 100
ln -s /usr/bin/clang-3.5 /usr/bin/clang
ln -s /usr/bin/clang++-3.5 /usr/bin/clang++
```

Another issue is that your container misses the `make` command. Install it with `apt-get install make`